# Classifying all numbers $n$ with the property that if $p$ is a prime, then $p \mid n \iff p-1 \mid n$

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

If a number $n$ has the property that if $p$ is a prime, then $p \mid n \iff p-1 \mid n$, we call $n$ a *nice* number for brevity.

A recent [question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181677/prime-factorization-and-divisibility-of-natural-numbers-proof-1806) (edit: now deleted) asks to prove that $1806$ is the only squarefree nice number. (That question gives no context and looks like a contest problem, and was therefore ill-received, but the actual question is a nice puzzle.) After solving it, I relayed the question to some friends, but initially I accidentally forgot the *squarefree* condition. This led me to wondering about nice numbers that are not necessarily squarefree.

A fairly simple argument proves that all nice numbers must be multiples of $1806$, and this is the first step towards solving the puzzle as well. (Edit: namely, for any nice $n$, we have $2-1 \mid n$, so $2 \mid n$; but then also $3 \mid n$. It follows that $6 \mid n$, and therefore $7 \mid n$. Then $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 = 42 \mid n$, so $43 \mid n$, and we obtain that $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 43 = 1806 \mid n$ -- but $1807$ is not prime, so the argument ends here.)

However, there are more examples that are not squarefree:

- $1806 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 43$.
- $12642 = 2 \times 3 \times 7^2 \times 43$.
- $88494 = 2 \times 3 \times 7^3 \times 43$.
- $6030842622 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 43^2 \times 77659$.

These are all examples up to $2 \times 10^{10}$ (via computer search). <strike>The sequence is not currently listed on OEIS.</strike> The sequence has now been listed, at [A345765](https://oeis.org/A345765).

My question is: can we classify all nice numbers? Are there only four? Are there more? Infinitely many?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126946/discussion-on-question-by-mees-de-vries-classifying-all-numbers-n-with-the-pro).

Answer (score 10):

## Summary

- This is not a complete answer, but I think it's about as far as is both
  feasible and interesting.
- I've started calling these numbers *saturated* rather than *nice*, and will
  do so for the rest of this answer.
- There are a lot more saturated numbers than listed in the question and
  comments, but they are nonetheless scarce: there are 126 below $10^{1000}$.
- I now conjecture that there are infinitely many.

## Downward/upward saturated

If $n$ has the property that for any prime $p$,
$$
    p \mid n \implies p-1 \mid n,
$$
we call it *downward saturated*. (This is equivalent to: $\lambda(n) \mid n$, where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function. This sequence is [A124240 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A124240).) If it has the property that for any prime $p$,
$$
    p - 1 \mid n  \implies p \mid n
$$
we call it *upward saturated*. Clearly $n$ is saturated if and only if it is
both downward and upward saturated.

Suppose $n$ is already downward saturated. Then we can define
$$
n' = n \times \prod \{p\text{ prime} \mid p \not \mid n, (p-1) \mid n\}.
$$

Note that:

- $n \mid n'$;
- $n'$ is still downward saturated: the primes $p$ that we added to $n'$ by
  construction have $p-1 \mid n$, and thus $p-1 \mid n'$;
- if $n \mid m$ and $m$ is saturated, then $n' \mid m$;
- in particular, $n = n'$ if and only if $n$ is saturated.

This gives a recipe for generating saturated numbers up to a cutoff $C$: start
with any downward saturated number $n$, and define the sequence $n, n', n'',
\ldots$. If it eventually stabilizes, you have found a saturated number. If the
sequence eventually exceeds $C$, then $n$ is not the divisor of any saturated
number below $C$.

Note that the sequence $n, n', n'', \ldots$ typically grows very fast when it
does not immediately stabilize: this allows us to quickly rule out $n$ and
search up to quite large cutoffs $C$.

It remains to be seen how we can find the right 'seeds' $n$ to start running
this generation algorithm.

## Bases and saturation primes

For a fixed cutoff $C$, the *(C-)saturation primes* are those primes which
occur as a prime factor of a saturated number below $C$. Note that we are
currently unable to rule out any prime factor from being a saturation prime for
*some* $C$.

If we know what the saturation primes are for a cutoff $C$, say $p_1, \ldots,
p_k$, we are essentially done: we simply generate all numbers of the form
$p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ that are below $C$, check whether they are
saturated, and we are done. Thus we need a procedure which finds these primes
for us.

Suppose we have found a partial list of the saturation primes $p_1, \ldots,
p_l$ (may be empty, but we may as well initialize with $2, 3, 7, 43$), and
there is a saturated number $K$ which is divided by a different prime. Let $q$
be the least prime divisor of $K$ which is not yet among our list. Then the
prime divisors of $q-1$ are among $p_1, \ldots, p_l$.

This means we have two strikes with one stone: we will enumerate all products
of powers of $p_1, \ldots, p_l$ that are below the cutoff. I call such numbers
*bases*. For each basis $n$, we construct the sequence $n, n', n'', \ldots$ as
above, until it exceeds the cutoff or until it saturates. Now note that $q - 1$
is a basis itself: this means it must be part of our enumeration, and through
it some saturated number $s$ such that $q-1 \mid s \mid K$. We can then add $q$
to our list of primes, and continue our search.

What remains are just tricks to speed up the computation:

- Short-circuit past bases that are not downward saturated.
- If the saturation sequence of a basis exceeds the cutoff, then so does the saturation sequence of each multiple of that basis, so we short-circuit past these as well.
- Rather than using the sequence $n, n', n'', \ldots$ as above, we only add one
  prime at a time, to avoid creating gargatuan numbers with an infeasible
  number of divisors.
- Keep track of each large number's factorization, so that we never have to
  factorize.

## Results

I have put my code implementing the above on Github: https://github.com/mjdv/saturated-numbers

With that code, I have listed all saturated numbers up to $10^{1000}$: https://pastebin.com/MkEfkSpY

I have also listed all saturated numbers up to $10^{1500}$, under the assumption that $7^4$ does not divide a saturated number below $10^{1500}$ (see below): https://pastebin.com/CT7hUDXi

There are 16 saturation primes for cutoff $10^{1000}$. They are
$$
2, 3, 7, 43, 77659, 21108889701347407, 5474088843701260097485589623,
5474159333397668466502066699,
14409061174110271629491692889111901658580261328754207,
12187898054314878179186265415000535659762253573563119365846458063397719,
4432982211548497951181997741316103259463454892983224005155108393681585716520...\\ 47036741930999,
5608017333924641389333679842752042439016754139199524596804923772035677581183...\\ 43740900139639,
1872705977981591020313336244505607714217889071693212286852076373413830346691...\\ 635632706249598340007,
9724040345982427116322290520909526374336288011833033457100867657726910715963...\\ 7823909035022095182893334450446173318074919,
3261106282862834686088755611243542924322840903892344944538844883173926466304...\\ 3468198518796043304218142825248440850700658152098958744500089400281673745399...\\ 0562312935495319926909431192160160253334732061914415799939878042598694784290...\\ 509218689159009145647650418769156819250302503,
3758874354521422972974642113256353902974703838722946991775778945748849417310...\\ 8680865452438274881828114249910402060654847053902299762834024507515311159860...\\ 0956871660411763936550716357782852055668471710382751800336614044465508091526...\\ 9963990635230724828608976209217399558456147493114652686096883786754935980432...\\ 41430009359.
$$
Edit: here are the same primes, in a compact notation suggested by @Vepir below: the primes are numbered $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, and a vector $(e_1, \ldots, e_k)$ stands for $p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k} + 1$.
$$
(),
(1,), 
(1, 1), 
(1, 1, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 9), 
(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 10, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 10), 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
(1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1).
$$
It seems to work as follows: once a saturation sequence incorporates a small
prime (apart from the few special ones in this list), it will no longer
stabilize. However, if it incorporates a large prime, this is fairly frequently
fine: the large prime does not cause a snowball effect. In fact, the number of
'safe' large primes grows fairly steadily. Up to cutoff $10^{1500}$, there are
at least 4 more. This leads me to the conjecture that there are infinitely many
saturated numbers.

There are two obstructions to searching larger ranges for saturated numbers:

- For large cutoffs, it is slow to check that the saturation sequence of $2
    \times 3 \times 7^4 \times 43$ diverges past the cutoff. I have checked this
  up to $10^{1000}$, and it takes up the majority of the computation time (hours,
  compared to minutes for the rest of the computation). The code linked above
  hard-codes this case as impossible, which allows listing all the other numbers up to $10^{1500}$ without too much patience.
- Primality checking of very large numbers is somewhat slow. This seems to be a
  fairly impenetrable barrier.

Some notes:

- It seems extremely unlikely that $4$ divides any saturated number (and therefore any prime of the form $4k + 1$). If it does, that saturated number must have more than 10,000 distinct prime factors.
- With the all the computational short-cuts, even for very large bounds, there are only a few-hundred paths $n, n', n'', \ldots$ that we follow through to either saturation or until they exceed the cutoff. Most are ruled out by earlier computations.

Comment: Instead of writing long digits, why not express saturation primes in a compact vector form? $$\begin{array}{} p_1 &=& (0)  &&  &=& 2 \\
p_2 &=& (1)  &=& 2^1 + 1  &=& 3 \\
p_3 &=& (1,1)  &=& 2^1 3^1 + 1 &=& 7 \\
p_4 &=& (1,1,1) &=& 2^1 3^1 7^1 + 1 &=& 43 \\
p_5 &=& (1,1,1,2) &=& 2^1 3^1 7^1 43^2 + 1 &=& 77659 \\
p_6 &=& (1,1,1,9) &=& p_1^1 p_2^1 p_3^1 p_4^9 +1 &=& 21108\dots \\
\dots && \dots && \dots && \dots\end{array}$$ I.e., write $v^{(n)}=(v^{(n)}_1,v^{(n)}_2,v^{(n)}_3,\dots,v^{(n)}_{n-1})$ for $ p_n = p_1^{v^{(n)}_1} p_2^{v^{(n)}_2} p_3^{v^{(n)}_3} \dots p_{n-1}^{v^{(n)}_{n-1}}+1.$

Comment: @Vepir, thank you for the suggestion, I have added them.